How to stop CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE spam in system logs
I've suddenly realized wpa_supplicant is spamming my system logs with these messages:
Sep 02 08:07:17 elite wpa_supplicant[3054]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=9999 txrate=648500
Sep 02 08:07:20 elite wpa_supplicant[3054]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-58 noise=9999 txrate=648500
Sep 02 08:07:23 elite wpa_supplicant[3054]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-58 noise=9999 txrate=648500
Sep 02 08:07:26 elite wpa_supplicant[3054]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=9999 txrate=648500
Sep 02 08:07:29 elite wpa_supplicant[3054]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=9999 txrate=432300
Sep 02 08:07:32 elite wpa_supplicant[3054]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-63 noise=9999 txrate=432300
Sep 02 08:07:35 elite wpa_supplicant[3054]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-63 noise=9999 txrate=576400
Sep 02 08:07:38 elite wpa_supplicant[3054]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=9999 txrate=576400
Sep 02 08:07:41 elite wpa_supplicant[3054]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=9999 txrate=576400
Sep 02 08:07:44 elite wpa_supplicant[3054]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-63 noise=9999 txrate=576400

I want this to stop. My WiFi works perfectly but these seemingly debug messages drive me insane and generate over 2GB of disk writes daily.
For the past three days:
journalctl | grep CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE | wc -l
24500

I'm using fully updated Fedora 40 with NetworkManager.

This should fix it:
cat /etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service.d/log.conf 
[Service]
LogLevelMax=2

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service

P.S. LogLevelMax=4 could be more preferrable, 2 silences the daemon a lot harder.

December 29, 2024 update:
This has now finally been fixed upstream. Ask your distro to apply the patch or push the latest version of the daemon.

Here is a dicussion about wpa_supplicant log flood in Fedora journalctl: https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/wpa-supplicant-logs/134579 while neither the discussion nor this Q&A says so, the lowest log level without the spam for me was LogLevelMax=4, i.e. the log spam happens on log level 5==Notice

I'm not sure why this would fix it?  You are just dumping out the contents of a file called log.conf and then restarting the service.  Did you mean "wpa_supplicant.conf"?

@Artem - Geez, chill, I'm just asking a question since nothing was actually changed in the posing.  If you meant to say "Edit the log.conf file and make sure the LogLevelMax=2 under the [Service] section." then just say that.  You issued a "cat" command.  You never said to edit a conf file.  Yes, you are right, it does work when I edit my "/etc/systemd/system/dbus-fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service" file.  I'm using xubuntu 24.04.  Have a great day.
